# How to view normal table data without metrics in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, javascript, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

I am sending custom event through code to Google Analytics.

```
gtag("event", "my_custom_event", {
    field1: "value1",
    field2: "value2",
});
```

I am unable to find a way to see this data in a normal table form in Explore.

```
[filed1]  | [field2]
value1    | value2
```

Anyway to make it appear like this or anything close to this? If having a metrics is necessary, it is okay to have it too as an extra column. But these two columns must be present.

Comment: I think metrics are required but your might be able to do something like this in Looker Studio.